# docker-compose build hangs in script with yarn install

Tags: docker, yarnpkg

I have this script where i put docker-compose build and it hangs at the end of the RUN yarn install:

```
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > @craco/craco@6.4.3" has incorrect peer dependency "react-scripts@^4.0.0".
warning "@craco/craco > cosmiconfig-typescript-loader@1.0.9" has unmet peer dependency "@types/node@*".
warning "@craco/craco > cosmiconfig-typescript-loader@1.0.9" has incorrect peer dependency "typescript@>=3".
warning "@craco/craco > cosmiconfig-typescript-loader > ts-node@10.8.1" has unmet peer dependency "@types/node@*".
warning " > @testing-library/user-event@12.8.3" has unmet peer dependency "@testing-library/dom@>=7.21.4".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 175.73s.
^CBuild complete.
```

You can see I interrupted the hang with ctrl+c and after that the it says "build complete".
This prevents my script to continue with docker-compose up...

I have this docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  
  frontend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/build/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    stdin_open: true
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - staticfiles:/app/static
      - mediafiles:/app/media
    depends_on:
      - backend
    networks:
      spa_network:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.128.3

  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/django/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    command: /start
    volumes:
      - staticfiles:/app/static
      - mediafiles:/app/media
      - sqlite_db:/app/db  
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - ./env/prod-sample
    networks:
      spa_network:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.128.2

networks:
  spa_network:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.0.0/16

volumes:
  sqlite_db:
  staticfiles:
  mediafiles:
```

and the build which is hanging has this dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14-stretch-slim as frontend-builder

WORKDIR /app/frontend
COPY ./frontend .
ENV PATH ./node_modules/.bin/:$PATH
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn build 

###############################################

FROM nginx:1.19.2-alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./compose/production/build/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
COPY --from=frontend-builder /app/frontend/build /usr/share/nginx/html/build
```

Notice the build is hanging only on first build. When i rerun the build process (docker-compose build) and it is in cache it is processing the next RUN command...

I've tried to use `sudo docker-compose up --build -d` but it's the same...maybe it has something to do with yarn?

The issue is described here : https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/6605
but they say it's not yarn

And they point to there https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/749#issuecomment-253317395 to use --no cache

I've tried to use --no cache and it is the same. It hangs after `"Done in x s."`

Comment: did you run `docker-compose up` with `-d` argument? (`docker-compose up -d`)

Comment: the command that is problematic is not docker-compose up but docker-compose build

Comment: I guess that actual problem is `stdin_open: true`. After build complete docker open `stdin` channel and waiting for input. But `nginx` doesn't handle stdin inputs so it is looking like `hangs`. I recommend to remove this line if you don't have reasons to listen from stdin

Comment: Oh i thought you were my hero...the line was there for yarn start configuration but it's useless for yarn build indeed. Unfortunately, i ve tried to remove it and it's the same

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, running the following commands :

```
   RUN set -ex; \
      yarn install --frozen-lockfile --production; \
      yarn cache clean; \
      yarn run build
```

instead of

```
RUN yarn install 
RUN yarn build
```

in the Dockerfile seems to work properly